# Could the Space X "Starship" be modified for point to point travel on Earth?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, sub-orbital

After seeing recent successes with the SN5 prototype, powered with very inexpensive LNG, designed to carry 100+ people, is this ... an airliner?

A suborbital Starship could make trans Atlantic and Pacific flights in a matter of minutes.

Suborbital flights require far less energy than orbital (or extra orbital), and would reach their destinations more than 10x faster than subsonic airliners.

Earth routes tend to have more volume than lunar or Martian ones.

Is this application a viable possibility, based on travel time (turnaround), ticket price, and fuel cost?

Comment: Probably no way with current regulations.

Comment: Ah, yes, regulations.  We'll have to check in with the heliports, and review Class airspace rules.

Comment: Suggest you read this paper: https://isulibrary.isunet.edu/doc_num.php?explnum_id=95 Great overview of suborbital commercial transportation issues & prospects. There's a whole chapter on regulation.

Comment: I just want to make clear that the user who asked the question is _not_ me. There might be suspicions because I asked a similar question.

Comment: Elon Musk has personally stated multiple times (on Twitter as well as in live presentations) that Earth-to-Earth capability (E2E) is possible and even a legitimate use case of Starship. Interestingly, Starship may not require the Superheavy booster for E2E because Starship is capable of suborbital flight on its own.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how the demand for a service for this will evolve. 6 months ago, I know some companies who would have killed for being able to send their engineers to the other side of the world within minutes. *During* the last 6 months, though, they have discovered that they can actually send their engineers around the world in *milliseconds* using a radical new technology called a "telephone".

Comment: Teleconferencing is indeed a possibility for working professionals, not a great way to vacation.  I'm seeing rocket ride out, cruise ship back packages, or, maybe 2 rocket rides and more time at your favorite island.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something SpaceX is actively planning. Elon Musk unveiled plans to use Starship for hypersonic passenger transport on Earth all the way back in September 2017, [during his "Making Life Multiplanetary" presentation](https://youtu.be/tdUX3ypDVwI?t=2423) at the International Astronautical Congress. SpaceX even released [a promotional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqE-ultsWt0) on the concept.

More recently in June 2020, Elon confirmed that Earth-to-Earth flights are still part of the plan, stating on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1272990764973166592):

> There will be many test flights before commercial passengers are carried. First Earth to Earth test flights might be in 2 or 3 years.

Whether or not it's viable as a profitable business is an open question subject to much debate, but Elon Musk certainly seems to think it is. Take that as you will.